# Как настроить запрос пароля каждый раз при доступе к ресурсу по smb?

Tags: windows, samba

Добрый день.

У меня есть NAS-сервер WD My Cloud EX4. Хотел его использовать в домене как хранилище для доступа к дистрибутивам. Но возникла проблема, при вводе в домен хранилка очень сильно зависает и я также не увидел изначально в спецификации что у нее максимум возможно 800 пользователей из AD и 200 групп. Т.к. у меня в домене сильно больше пользователей и групп, решил использовать ее без ввода в домен через заведенную в хранилке учетку, но и тут меня постигла неудача.

После того как я захожу на ресурс, система запрашивает пароль и создает сессию:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого я закрываю проводник, и при следующей попытке зайти на ресурс учетный данные уже не запрашиваются (только если удалить сессию через net use /d или перелогиниться).

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли настроить как-то эту связку, чтобы учетные данные запрашивались каждый раз? Заранее спасибо =)

P.S. Также на просторах сети находил, что можно убирать в групповых политиках кеширование паролей, но это на результат никак не повлияло.

Comment: Ну есть вариант с `net use * /del`. Осталось придумать как его запихнуть в событие закрытия проводника.

Comment: В теории я представляю как это сделать, если написать какое-то отдельное приложение, висящее в фоне и контролирующее состояние проводника, но мне такой вариант не подойдет, а как сделать это нативными средствами Windows я даже и не представляю :(

Comment: @German У вас доступ всем на все предоставляется? Или вы хотите разграничить доступ?

Comment: @1d0 В принципе, в рамках хранилища доступ будет дан всем и на все, точнее там вообще можно будет сделать одного пользователя и через него ходить. Проблема в следующем: прихожу я на рабочее место пользователя, и мне нужно что-то взять с хранилища, я ввожу учетные данные, копирую информацию, закрываю explorer и ухожу. Мне нужно чтобы в дальнейшем пользователь не мог зайти на хранилище. Но т.к. сессия остается, он может это сделать.

Comment: @German попробуйте после закрытия проводника, выполнить `klist /purge`

Comment: @1d0 где-то я уже находил это в сети, но как и у того человека, у меня эта команда никак не повлияла на результат